# Seamless Video Playback Using Media Foundation

Tags: c++, ms-media-foundation, audiovideoplayback

I have been trying to achieve Seamless video playback using Microsofts Media Foundation and C++. I have successfully created a playlist and have videos that play in a loop but it is far from seamless. Depending on the file format there is anywhere from 300ms gap to as much as 1.5 to 2 seconds gaps between videos. The Sequencer Source in Media Foundations is supposed to offer seamless video playback but so far I have see no such result. Has anyone achieved seamless video playback using Media Foundation and if so can you please advise me. If it is not possible can you point me in a direction to continue my search?

Answer (score 0):

I have had exactly the same results. Media Foundation is not fully functional (probably never will be, because it's been here for a long time and it's still buggy). The transformers are functional and good. But, if you need playback, capturing, or similar higher level functionality I strongly suggest writing your own code for that. Or, use DirectShow if that's acceptable alternative. Or maybe some DShow/MF combination...